# Lightning Input field's value is undefined, even if it has value

Tags: javascript, salesforce, undefined, apex, salesforce-lightning

**Component :**

```
<aura:if isTrue="{!v.internal}">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="To__c" class = "customRequired" value = "{!v.mailTo}" required="true"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.external}">
                <lightning:layoutItem size="6" padding="horizontal-small">
                    <lightning:inputField fieldName="ToExternal__c" class = "customRequired" value = "{!v.mailExtTo}" required="true"/>
                </lightning:layoutItem>
            </aura:if>
```

**Helper :**

```
var toMail = component.get("v.mailTo");
var toExtMail = component.get("v.mailExtTo");
```

Why is it coming undefined, even if I populate some value in the form?

Comment: maybe post the entire component. Do you have any `<aura:attribute>` tags for 'mailTo' and 'mailExtTo'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know what the problem is without the entire component code. Do you have 'aura:attribute' tags for these fields? If you don't then I believe using `component.get("v.mailTo");` will not work as it is attempting to get an attribute that just doesn't exist. To get the value of the input field directly you could try adding the `aura:id="someId"` attribute to the `<lightning:inputfield/>` tags and then access them this way:
`var toMail = component.find("someId").get("v.value");` so you could try that out.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didnt have the attribute for one of the input field.